# Single Sub Document in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can we define a schema for a single nested sub document. I don't want to use array of subdocuments.

My Schema is like

```
var user = new Schema({
    name: String,
    address: {
        city: String,
        State: String
    }
});
```

Data is not inserted into sub-document when we add document but we are able to add sub-document during update.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to post some sample code which you are using to insert/update data, so that we know what's wrong.

Comment: My schema is
<code></code>

Comment: you need to show the code you're using to save, not just the schema